# Is it possible to manipulate: $\frac{x^2 -2}{x+1}$ such that the numerator has a lower power than the denominator?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

Is it possible to manipulate: $\frac{x^2 -2}{x+1}$ such that the numerator has a lower power than the denominator?

For example: $\frac{x+3}{x+2}$ would be $1+\frac{1}{x+2}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**
$$\frac{x^2 -2}{x+1}=\frac{x^2 -1}{x+1}-\frac{1}{x+1}$$

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{x^2-2}{x+1}=\frac{x^2-1-1}{x+1}=\frac{(x-1)(x+1)-1}{x+1}=x-1-\frac{1}{x+1}$$

In general, we can perform division of polynomial. When $x^2-2$ is divided by $x+1$, the quotient is $x-1$ and the remainder is $-1$.

$$x^2-2=(x-1)(x+1)-1$$

Answer (score 3):

This is the result of the polynomial division between $x^2-2$ and $x+1$:
$$
{x^2-2\over x+1}={(x^2+2x+1)-(2x+2)+(2-1-2)\over x+1}=x-1-{1\over x+1}
$$

Answer (score 1):

This requires nothing smart: just do long division.

$$
\begin{array}{c|c}
\begin{array}[t]{r}
\hphantom{-}x^2+0x-2 \\
-x^2-\hphantom{0}x\hphantom{{}-0} \\
\hline
-x-2\\
x+1\\
\hline
-1
\end{array}
&
\begin{array}[t]{l}
x+1\\[4px]
\hline
x-1
\end{array}
\end{array}
$$

Or with an abbreviated scheme:
$$
\begin{array}{r|rr|r}
& 1 & 0 & -2 \\
-1 & & -1 & 1 \\
\hline
& 1 & -1 & -1
\end{array}
$$
Both tell you that
$$
x^2-2=(x-1)(x+1)-1
$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is always possible when dividing one polynomial by another. Suppose we start with
$$\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$$
where $P(x)=a_nx^n+$ lower-order terms, and $Q(x)=b_mx^m+$ lower-order terms, with $n \ge m$. Then we have
$$\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}=\frac{a_n}{b_m}x^{n-m}+\frac{R(x)}{Q(x)}$$
where
$$R(x)=P(x)-\frac{a_n}{b_m}x^{n-m}Q(x)$$
is a polynomial of degree $\le n-1$ (because its $n^\text{th}$-order coefficient is $a_n-\frac{a_n}{b_m}b_m=0$).

You can repeat this process with $R(x)/Q(x)$, until you end up with
$$\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}=S(x)+\frac{T(x)}{Q(x)}$$
where $S$ is a polynomial of degree $n-m$ and $T$ is a polynomial of degree $\le m-1$.

In practice, this process is very simple. At each step, you just look at the highest-order terms in the fraction, and the next term of $S$ is their quotient.